# compute the following integral in closed form : $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^b)}{x^2+ax+1})dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

Find :

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^b)}{x^2+ax+1}\,dx$$

where $b>0$ , $a\in \Bbb R$.

I don't know if this integral have a closed form but my try as follow : 
at first I divide integral $\int_0^{1}+\int_1^{\infty}$

I use sub :

$y=\frac{1}{x}$ then $dy=-\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$.

$$I=\int_0^{1}\mkern-5mu\frac{\ln(1+x^b)}{x^2+ax+1}+\int_0^{1}\!\frac{\ln(1+x^b)-b\ln x}{x^2+ax+1}=2\int_0^{1}\mkern-5mu\frac{\ln(1+x^b)}{x^2+ax+1}-\int_0^{1}\mkern-6mu\frac{\ln x}{x^2+ax+1}$$

But how I complete this work ?

Comment: The latter integral yet alone is worth an own post. Evaluating some the value for some $a\in\Bbb N$ manually I cannot spot an obvious pattern. However, they are expressable in terms of Dilogarithm, Trigamma Functions and known constant but I see no hope for an arbitrary chosen real number.